# Document name not changing after saving doc and saving blank doc

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, vsto, add-in

I am try to save doc. usning my extended savefile dialog but after saving my document name not changing and blank doc is been save.

```
  private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
       
            Frorsavedialog controlex = new Frorsavedialog();
            controlex.StartLocation = AddonWindowLocation.Bottom;
            controlex.DefaultViewMode = FolderViewMode.Thumbnails;
            controlex.OpenDialog.InitialDirectory = Path.GetFullPath(Application.ExecutablePath);
            controlex.OpenDialog.Filter = "Word Document (*.docx)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
            controlex.OpenDialog.FilterIndex = 1;
           controlex.OpenDialog.DefaultExt = ".docx";
            controlex.OpenDialog.FileName = ".docx";
            controlex.OpenDialog.AddExtension = true;
            controlex.OpenDialog.RestoreDirectory = true;
            controlex.OpenDialog.CheckFileExists = false;
            controlex.ShowDialog(this);
            controlex.OpenDialog.OpenFile();
            controlex.Dispose();
            this.Dispose();


        }
```

Comment: I have no idea what you're actually doing. But your filter expression seems to be wrong and should be "Word Document (*.docx)|*.docx|..." if youre trying to save docx

Comment: So where are you actually saving anything? It seems you just open the file and then... nothing.

Comment: @KlausGütter i have created word doc plugin , if user try to save word doc. my custom save dialog should appear to save doc, i have no idea how to use 'stream' to save document